# How to create 3 instances of command prompt in Windows and pass commands to each prompt in parallel using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I am using python 3.2 currently and I wanted to do write a code that generates 3 instances of command prompt in windows. I then need to access a different server in each of these command prompts using Plink (putty) and run a time consuming program in each of these command prompts in parallel. While I was able to create three instances of command prompts, I was not able to send commands to these prompts. Is there any method to do so? Should I use multiprocessing/ multithreading for this purpose?

I wrote the following code for creating the command prompts. Is there any way to pass commands to each of these prompts?

```
def Plink():
    name = multiprocessing.current_process().name
    proc = subprocess.Popen("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Plink_1 = multiprocessing.Process(name='Plink 1', target=Plink)
    Plink_2 = multiprocessing.Process(name='Plink 2', target=Plink)
    Plink_3 = multiprocessing.Process(name='Plink 3', target=Plink)

    Plink_1.start()
    Plink_2.start()
    Plink_3.start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um, what?

```
import subprocess
def make_shells(n):
    for i in range(n):
         subprocess.Popen(["cmd.exe"])
```

What you want to do isn't what is generally referred to as "multi-processing"...

## Using Paramiko

Here's how you can use paramiko to connect to a remote SSH server and run a command.

```
import paramiko
def run_ls_la():
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.connect("myssh.server.org", username="foo", password="bar")
    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command("ls -la")
    print(stdout.read())
```

You can also have it use public key auth, check the docs.

Comment: Hey after some debugging, I did find the cause of the initial problem. It was an issue with passing the commands to the prompt due to which the prompt would not be created at all. Sorry about the terminologies, I am pretty new to multitasking/multiprocessing. I have modified the question to give more clarity. Thanks for your comment

Comment: @Pulimon: You're approaching this from the wrong direction, and doing that wrong, too. You don't need to use the `multiprocessing` package if all you're doing is starting new processes - the processes start anyway! Just have 3 calls to `subprocess.Popen`. Furthermore, what you're trying to achieve with that is rather convulted. What you want to do is open an SSH connection to a remote server and run a program. So get a SSH2 implementation for Python, like [paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/), and use that.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But does paramiko work with python 3.x? Their site specifies python 2.2+ but I couldn't find any specific mention of Python 3 :(

Comment: @Pulimon: There seems to be a Python 3.x compatible fork at https://github.com/bitprophet/ssh